# Application of threshold functions from random graph theory

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, applications

I would like to know if anyone knows about some applications/models where those threshold functions from random graph theory, defined by
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\mathbb{G}_{n,p} \in \mathcal{F}) = 
    \begin{cases}
        0 \text{ if } p/p_c \to 0 \\
        1 \text{ if } p/p_c \to \infty
    \end{cases}
$$
are used for. As they describe some kind of phase transition I could imagine they could be used for modelling physical phase transitions (like water to ice etc.) but I haven't encountered a model so far.

Comment: The more physics-related cases are problems of bond percolation, which are a similar model to $\mathbb G_{n,p}$, but with a different host graph the edges are sampled from (usually, a lattice graph).